# How to compile forked library in Gradle?

Tags: android, git, github, gradle, android-studio

I want to compile the following library in my project in `build.gradle`:

https://github.com/theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap

It is forked from https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap, but no documentation in the repository explains how to include in in project.

I tried something like this:

```
compile 'com.theDazzler:androidbootstrap:+'
```

but gradle failed and shows error that library not found.

**Edit:** Can anyone fork it and/or publish it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This fork **isn't published** in the maven central repo.

Then you **can't use** an import like `compile com.theDazzler:androidbootstrap:+`

You have to:
- clone this library locally as a module in your project
Clone the 
https://github.com/theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap/tree/master/AndroidBootstrap folder in your root/module1 folder.

```
  root:
      module1
        build.gradle
      app
        build.gradle
      settings.gradle
```

- Change your settings.gradle file in

  include ':module1'
  include ':app'

In your app/build.gradle file you have to add:

```
dependencies {
    // Module Library
    compile project(':module1')
}
```

Finally in your module1/build.gradle you have to check the level used for gradle plugin.

**EDIT 31/10/2015:**

You can use another way to add a dependency with a github project,using the github repo and the [**jitpack** plugin](https://jitpack.io/)
In this case you have to add this repo tp your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

and the dependency:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

Comment: can't you fork it and make a new repo and then publish it?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Hello Sir, could you possibly help me out with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157555/3287204) ? Thank you ... :)

Comment: Please, note that you want to take *module* folder and include it in your project, not the whole project

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti would you mind answering my question around your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070764/how-to-compile-a-specific-github-pr-into-my-android-studio-project-grade-error

Comment: 'Cannot invoke method include() on null object' it show me that error can you teel me why ?!

Answer (score 7):

It can be simply done by using Jitpack.

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file

```
allprojects {
        repositories {

            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
    }
```

for eg: **compile 'com.github.sachinvarma:JcPlayer:0.0.1'**

Comment: Would you mind answering this around your solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070764/how-to-compile-a-specific-github-pr-into-my-android-studio-project-grade-error

Comment: what is the Tag ? what i can put in it ... is it just a number ?!

Comment: No, Tag is the release version of the Library.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is: has that `theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap` been published anywhere? In any gradle/maven repo? 
The usual [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/AndroidBootstrap/android-bootstrap/blob/master/app/build.gradle) file has a section `repositories` which should reference that maven repo.

So it is possible any project using [`theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap`](https://github.com/theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap) should reference the repo where it is published, And with a project like [`gradle-git-repo-plugin`](https://github.com/layerhq/gradle-git-repo-plugin), you could publish that fork on its own [release section](https://github.com/theDazzler/Android-Bootstrap/releases) to publish it.

> That task gets wrapped into a `publishToGithub` task that handles committing and pushing the change. Then you can run

```
gradle -Porg=layerhq -Prepo=gradle-releases publishToGithub
```

> You can also run

```
gradle -Porg=layerhq -Prepo=gradle-releases publish
```

> to stage a release in the local github repo and commit it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Hi i had the same issue but with a different project :)

So first you should have the library code on your dev machine.
Next steps are: add a new file called **settings.gradle** to the root of your project if its not already there.

inside add this:

```
include 'AndroidBootStrap'
project('AndroidBootStrap').path = "path/to/AndroidBootstrap/AndroidBootStrapLibrary"
```

also add include for your root project if its not there.
Inside your **build.gradle** file add

```
compile project(':AndroidBootStrap')
```

to add the dependency.

How your folder Structure should look:

```
 root
   YourProject
      settings.gradle
      YourProjectModule
          build.gradle

   AndroidBootStrap
      AndroidBootStrapLibrary
          build.gradle
```

In the end the files look like this:

settings.gradle:

```
include 'AndroidBootStrap'
project('AndroidBootStrap').path = "../AndroidBootstrap/AndroidBootStrapLibrary"
include 'YourProjectModule'
```

build.gradle (YourModule):

```
...
dependencies {
   ...
   compile project(':AndroidBootStrap')
}
```

Maybe its necessary to modify some point but i hope you get the idea!

Cheers
Neri

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the current answers for a bit, I came up with the following solution in case you're working with `[...].kts` files.

Assuming that your library is in the same directory as your project as inticated in [Gabriele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910140/how-to-compile-forked-library-in-gradle/28524147#28524147):

- Add `include(":my-forked-library")` in `settings.gradle.kts`
- Add `implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":my-forked-library")))` to the `dependencies` part of your project's `build.gradle.kts`, something like this:

```kotlin
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":my-forked-library")))
}
```