# how to compile a specific github PR into my Android studio project - grade Error: Failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am pretty new to Android Studio, please bear with me.

I am trying to add this specific pull request into my project because I need the animation duration too and the original owner hasn't merged the request:
https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView/pull/74

I read on: [How to compile forked library in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910140/how-to-compile-forked-library-in-gradle)

that I can use `jitpack` for this. So I added:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

into my Project gradle file and

tried

```
compile 'com.github.kizitonwose:AVLoadingIndicatorView:2.1.3'
```

into my module gradle file. But when I sync gradle, I get error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.kizitonwose:AVLoadingIndicatorView:2.1.3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just pull it through git bash

`git checkout particularFork`

`git pull origin particularfork`

`git branch new_branch_where_i_use_library`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not having any Github account, please create one account, now fork the project  **https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView** ,then pull down the project and open it up in Android Studio and make the changes in the code then push back the project and finally create a release then make use of [How to compile forked library in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910140/how-to-compile-forked-library-in-gradle/44765941?noredirect=1#comment83115232_44765941).

Hope it may help you.