# Android Studio - Bibliotecas Github ZXing

Tags: android, github, shared-libraries

Recently I started to venture into Android Studio, and one of the projects I'm working on requires a barcode reader, and a great solution I found was the ZXing library.

However, the following doubts arose:

To use this library I used the following commands:

```
   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
   compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

If the owner removes this library, will the next build of the application no longer have this library?

If not, would you have any way to work with it local / offline?

Answer (score 0):

A compile directive works because the library is published in the maven central repo.

If you really want to secure that library, you would need to vendor it:

- clone it in your own project
- declare it as a module

Or: use the [jitpack project](https://jitpack.io/), which allows you to reference a fork (your own GitHub copy) of the project in a compile directive.

See more at "[How to compile forked library in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524147/6309)".